# Problem related to Gamma ($\Gamma$) function.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, gamma-function, beta-function

I have to prove the following equation

$$\frac{\Gamma(\frac{m}{2})\Gamma(\frac{m+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n+m}{2})}=2^n\times\frac{\Gamma(m
)\Gamma(\frac{m+n+1}{2})}{\Gamma(n+m)}$$

I started  by considering the RHS of the above equation.

I'm not getting how to

- put denominator 2 under $(n+m)$ of RHS
- get rid of $\frac{n}{2}$ from the $N^r$ of RHS.

Is there any formula(Linearity type) which can help me adjust powers of 2 to get LHS?

Comment: @metamorphy: on applying duplication formula on RHS I got,$2^n\times\frac{\Gamma(m
)\Gamma(\frac{m+n+1}{2})}{\Gamma(n+m)}\tag{1}=2^{3n}\times \frac{\Gamma(2m)\Gamma(\frac{m+n+1}{2})\times \Gamma(n+m+\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(m+\frac{1}{2})\Gamma(2n+2m)}$.Still not getting glimpse of the desired result...

Comment: It's the *other* way. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [duplication formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Gamma_function%E2%80%93Legendre_formula) for $\Gamma(m)$ and $\Gamma(n+m)$, we have
$$\frac{\Gamma(m)\Gamma(\frac{m+n+1}{2})}{\Gamma(n+m)}=\frac{\color{DarkBlue}{2^{m-1}\Gamma(\frac{m}{2})\Gamma(\frac{m+1}{2})}\color{gray}{[/\sqrt{\pi}]}\Gamma(\frac{m+n+1}{2})}{\color{DarkBlue}{2^{m+n-1}\Gamma(\frac{n+m}{2})\Gamma(\frac{n+m+1}{2})}\color{gray}{[/\sqrt{\pi}]}}=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{m}{2})\Gamma(\frac{m+1}{2})}{2^n\Gamma(\frac{n+m}{2})}.$$